# How can I make a user input 20 be read by the program as 20% or 0.20

Tags: java

This is the part where I ask the user to input the following.

Enter the item name:  Shirt

Original price of the item: 700

Marked-up Percentage: 20

Sales Tax Rate: 7

**Output**:

`Item to be sold : Shirt`
`Original price of the item: 700.00`
`Price after mark-up:        840.00`
`Sales tax:                  58.80`
`Final price of item:        898.80`

so my question is how can I make that 20 and 7 input be read by the program as percentages.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class lab3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane jo=new JOptionPane();
    String item=jo.showInputDialog("Item to be sold: ");
    double Oprice=Double.parseDouble(
            jo.showInputDialog("Original price of the item: "));
    double mup=Double.parseDouble(
            jo.showInputDialog("Marked-up percentage: "));   
    double str=Double.parseDouble(
            jo.showInputDialog("Sales Tax Rate: "));


    double pamu=(Oprice*mup)+Oprice;
    double ST=pamu*str;
    double result=pamu+ST;

    String hold= "\n| Item to be sold \t: "+item+"\t |"
                +"\n| Original price of the item \t: "+Oprice+"\t |"
                +"\n| Price after mark-up \t: "+pamu+"\t |"
                +"\n| Sales Tax \t: "+ST+"\t |"
                +"\n| Final price of the item \t: "+result+"\t |";
    jo.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(hold));
    }
    }
```

That is my actual code. sorry if its messy. like I said still new to this

Comment: Hint: what happens if you divide by 100? (Making sure you're performing floating point arithmetic...)

Comment: don't use floats or doubles though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Where's your actual code?

Comment: I really don't know how to add my actual code.. I'm still new to this. sorry

Comment: I do not understand the question, what exactly is going wrong? I mean 700 + 20% = 840, as already being calculated/output by the code - same for rest of calculations.

Comment: I already got the my answer thank you all

Comment: @johnfelix there is a "?" when entering/editing question for help which also has a link to [advanced help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... and **thank you** for answering my question [:-(

Comment: The output does not match the code - why have you removed part of the code??? Accepting a non-working answer ?!?!!!!  are you trying to get reputation ??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter item name:");
String item;
keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Original Price of item:");
double originalPrice;
keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Marked up percentage:");
double markedUpPercentage;
keyboard.nextDouble();
markedUpPercentage = markedUpPercentage/100; //this is what you want
System.out.println("Sales tax rate:");
double salesTaxRate;
keyboard.nextDouble();
salesTaxRate = salesTaxRate/100; //same thing here

//now output
System.out.println("Item to be sold: " + item);
System.out.println("Original price of the item: " + originalPrice);
System.out.println("Price after mark up: " + (originalPrice + originalPrice * markedUpPrice));
//similarly, do for sales tax
```

Comment: My bad, didn't notice that. There was no code in the question itself so I assumed wrong.

Comment: @johnfelix just copy paste it into the editor. Leave 4 spaces before you paste for the editor to understand what you are pasting is code.

Comment: does that really work? compile? at least this is **not Java**! e.g. `nextLine` does not take any argument, neither does `nextDouble`!! and Java is pass-by-value, I expected something like `item = keyboard.nextLine()`... and since you already toke time to edit the answer, why not delete the "Since you haven't specified..." part at all?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `Scanner` for reading from user:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double percentage = 0.01 * sc.nextInt();
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

```
double pamu = (Oprice*(mup/100)) + Oprice; // enter code here
double ST = pamu*(str/100) ;
double result = pamu+ST ;
```

I think this should work.